# RPM Build - Permission Denied

Tags: rpm, permission-denied, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have a Python-based SVN pre-commit script that generates an `rpmbuild` `.spec` file and runs `rpmbuild -bb my.spec` via `subprocess`.  The current state is:

1) When doing an SVN commit (SVN over SSH) remotely the `rpmbuild` fails with...

```
error: failed to create directory %{_topdir}: /rpmbuild: Permission denied
```

2) When I `rpmbuild -bb my.spec` (local on the SVN server) it completes successfully

I have `~/.rpmmacros`...

```
%_topdir /tmp/rpmbuild
```

When doing #2 (above) `rpmbuild` will create `BUILD`, `BUILDROOT`, `RPMS`, `SOURCES`, `SPECS`, and `SRPMS` under `/tmp/rpmbuild` and an RPM is created in `RPMS`.

From the command line, if I `rpm --showrc` the dirs are as I expect (and should be which is why the process completes successfully).

But I have different results from the process running via pre-commit...

Command line...
`-14: _topdir   /tmp/rpmbuild`

Pre-commit...
`-14: _topdir   %{getenv:HOME}/rpmbuild`

I suspect this is the problem and I do not know how to correct this.  I also tried:

1) To set the path in `my.spec`... `%define _topdir /tmp/rpmbuild` which gave the same permission denied error.

2) To set the path in the rpmbuild command... `rpmbuild --define='_topdir /tmp/rpmbuild'` which resulted in `error: Macro % has illegal name (%define)`.

Your expertise in resolving this appreciated; thanks very much!

Comment: Is your pre-commit script trying to run `rpmbuild`? Or just use the `SPECS` directory to create the `.spec` file?

Comment: Pre-commit runs `rpmbuild -bb my.spec` via `subprocess`.

Comment: Why is your pre-commit hook trying to build an rpm? Is that some sort of build-validation process? Is that cheap enough to make sense there?

Comment: Yes, if rpmbuild fails the commit is blocked.  Cheap enough?  I don't understand.

Comment: I'm surprised that the time it takes to build the rpm is short enough that that is a reasonably pre-commit delay to be adding. That's all.

Comment: Oh I understand.  Yes, it's pretty quick.  Of the three packages (at this point) that it will handle the longest build takes about 10 seconds.  Engineering dudes are now requiring all code be deployed via RPMs... replacing a shell script run via cron that grabs tarballs via HTTP and expands into particular dirs along with a tiny bit more magic.

Comment: Surely this problem has not stumped the community!  Did I not give enough info, too much, poorly presented??

Comment: I don't think you can set things like _topdir in a spec file. I think that's too late. When you tried `--define` did you have the `%define _topdir` line in the spec file still? Do you know what line of the spec file that error was coming from? Can you run `rpm --showrc` in the pre-commit hook and see what it spits out? Also `env` in the hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing piece is the file...

```
/etc/rpm/macros
```

I created `/etc/rpm` and the file `macros` populated with my needed `%_topdir...`.  After doing so `_topdir` is available to `rpmbuild` and my process completes successfully.  This was discovered by running `rpmbuild` through `strace`.

Answer (score 1):

That error means `$HOME` is unset when pre-commit runs (so your `.rpmmacros` file isn't being used and `${getenv:HOME}` is evaluating to the empty string).

I don't know why that would be (perhaps an svn change) but that seems to be the issue.